# Using lua_checkstack?

Tags: lua, luajit

I'm a little confused on how `lua_checkstack` is supposed to be used.

Docs say:

> ```
> int lua_checkstack (lua_State *L, int extra);
> ```
>
> Ensures that there are at least extra free stack slots in the stack. It returns false if it cannot grow the stack to that size. This function never shrinks the stack; if the stack is already larger than the new size, it is left unchanged.

In 3.2 Stack Size it says:

> When you interact with Lua API, you are responsible for ensuring consistency. In particular, you are responsible for controlling stack overflow. You can use the function lua_checkstack to grow the stack size.
>
> Whenever Lua calls C, it ensures that at least LUA_MINSTACK stack positions are available. LUA_MINSTACK is defined as 20, so that usually you do not have to worry about stack space unless your code has loops pushing elements onto the stack.

The only way you can use additional slots on the stack is by calling certain functions from the C API (for example `lua_pushnumber`, `lua_pushstring`) - right?

And those functions grow the stack as needed:

For example here is lua_pushnumber definition:

```
LUA_API void lua_pushnumber(lua_State *L, lua_Number n)
{
  setnumV(L->top, n);
  if (LJ_UNLIKELY(tvisnan(L->top)))
    setnanV(L->top);  /* Canonicalize injected NaNs. */
  incr_top(L); // <---- HERE
}
```

and this is incr_top definition:

```
#define incr_top(L) \
  (++L->top >= tvref(L->maxstack) && (lj_state_growstack1(L), 0))
```

I think that means if you push beyond the size of the stack it will grow it as needed anyway up to `LUA_MAXSTACK` anyway, and then fail gracefully with a stack overflow.  `lj_state_growstack` is what `lua_checkstack` calls.  So why would I ever call `lua_checkstack` ?

Comment: The quote you have posted is from Lua 5.1 manual.  Vanilla Lua 5.1 has the following: `#define api_incr_top(L)   {api_check(L, L->top < L->ci->top); L->top++;}`, so no stack check is automatically done for regular Lua 5.1 build.  LuaJIT is a Lua 5.1 clone with improvements, one of which you just have found.  But LuaJIT must be compatible with Lua 5.1, so it must implement `lua_checkstack`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Ahh I see now, so LuaJIT automatically grows the stack but the (vanilla) Lua reference implementation doesn't.  This explains the disparity between the manual and LuaJIT.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion was caused by:

1. LuaJIT automatically grows the stack as needed (to `LUA_MAXSTACK`).
2. The (vanilla) Lua reference implementation doesn't (crashes or undefined behaviour at `LUA_MINSTACK` without a call to `lua_checkstack`)

and the manual was describing 2.